# Form two Textfields in one row

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to set two Text fields in one row in the from class. That they loke like this:

> Name/surname ______    _______

I can't find something in the Internet.
I use this code in the Form class:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('surname', TextareaType::class);
    }
```

But this will be shown like this:

> Name ____

> surname ____

and this is wrong in my situation. Is it possible to do that in the form class?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not purely in the form type, but should be easy enough to do in twig by using the [specific form functions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-functions) for each component.

Comment: Thanks for the help @msg it’s helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show your **form_rows** in a more custom way by doing this:

Instead of showing your form in the more universal way:

```
{{ form_start(myForm) }}
{{ form_widget(myForm) }}
{{ form_end(myForm) }}
```

You can, in fact, do the next:

```
{{ form_start(myForm) }}
{{ form_row(myForm.field1) }}
{{ form_row(myForm.field2) }}
{{ form_widget(myForm) }}
{{ form_end(myForm) }}
```

This will allow you to show those rows how you want with extra arguments, and it will continue to show the rest, so **you do not need to use** `form_row` **for every row once you have started using it.**

Now, you can achieve what you are asking using **display: flex**, and setting it's direction as **row**.

Using **bootstrap**:

```
{{ form_start(myForm) }}
<div class = "d-flex flex-row">
    {{ form_row(myForm.field1) }}
    {{ form_row(myForm.field2) }}
</div>
{{ form_widget(myForm) }}
{{ form_end(myForm) }}
```

Without **bootstrap**:

```
{{ form_start(myForm) }}
<div style = "display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
    {{ form_row(myForm.field1) }}
    {{ form_row(myForm.field2) }}
</div>
{{ form_widget(myForm) }}
{{ form_end(myForm) }}
```

You can put the label you want only to field1, and so, `field 2`, without a label, will appear as you are asking, next to the input field of `field 1`.